# Mysql count with group BY join and case

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have below tables,

packages

```
id, package_name
```

tests

```
id, test_name, test_type
```

test_package_mapping

```
id, test_id, package_id
```

Now i want to fetch count of mapped tests for a particular package_id with test types

Example:

i have two tests types

```
1. MCQ
2. Answer Upload
```

SO i want to fetch the count of mapped tests like below,

```
mcqtestcount : 30
answeruploadtestcount: 20
```

in test_package_mapping sometimes by mistake test_id will be duplicated so i want to add group by as well,

so far i tried query like below,

```
$packageid = 131;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(case when u.test_type ='MCQ' then 1 end)) AS test_count,
                COUNT(DISTINCT(case when u.test_type ='Answer Upload' then 1 end)) AS answeruploadtestcount
                FROM tests AS u
                INNER JOIN (
                     SELECT test_id
                     FROM test_package_maping
                     WHERE test_package_maping.package_id = $packageid
                     GROUP BY test_package_maping.test_id
                ) AS a ON a.test_id = u.test_id where u.test_type = 'Mains'";
$testscount = DB::select($sql);
```

Above query is not working and when i try different method to get count with group by it is showing 1 even though it has more records.
Any solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result by grouping by test_type in the joined table of both `tests` and `test_package_mapping`.

Please try to use the following SQL.

And you need to add an index on `test_type` column in tests table.

```
SELECT
  t.test_type,
  COUNT (t.id) AS testCount
FROM
  tests AS t
  INNER JOIN test_package_mapping m
    ON t.id = m.test_id
WHERE m.package_id = $ packageid
GROUP BY t.test_type;
```

Comment: can you please explain why we need to use test_type for group by? test_id will be repeated in test_package_mapping table so i thought to add group by for test_id to remove duplicates

Comment: @DeekshithPrakash we should not group by for test_id because we have to count test_id for the specified package.

Comment: @DeekshithPrakash To improve SQL performance, you need to add an index on test_type.

Comment: Yes but test_type is static we have only two test  types. in test_package_mapping table we will map test for packages consider if test _id = 1 and package =1 then in table if we insert same data twice then using group by we should remove duplicate one.

Comment: @DeekshithPrakash mapping table can hold duplicated test_id because package may have multiple tests? Not sure about your data modeling for biz, but I just assumed that it should be like according to your table designs. Additionally, your db design (separated tables and mapping table) is one what I love and like to use in db design. :)

Comment: Please check my another explanation in answer section.

Comment: @DeekshithPrakash Your mapping table doesn't seem to be designed correctly. In mapping table, you could remove `id` column and need to set PK (test_id and package_id) to prevent duplicated row (4th row). And again, because you need to count of test_id per test_type, you should group by table by test_type.

Comment: @DeekshithPrakash if you show me the real data, I can assist you to design db tables. As you know, we should extract tables and normalize tables based on real data. Mapping table is required to design and normalize n:m relationship (e.g. tests and packages table)

Comment: test_package_maping acts as pivot table as it has already filles with real data i should write a query for this. here id acts as primary key and test_id and package_id are foreign keys

Comment: @DeekshithPrakash why do you need to allow duplication in mapping table? 3rd and 4th row. I can't understand it logically. If you allow duplication, it should be considered in the counting. But you mentioned `example: if i want to fetch package_id 1 total mapped tests count then i should get count = 3 instead of 4`. A bit confused.